# Magento - Changing the string in value in E-mail templates

Tags: magento, email, templates

So I've checked all the documenation on the variables in e-mail templates.  Did a entire sql dump and ran a string search but unable to find where to change the string value of the shipping method.

var order.getshippingdescription

where does this get its string value? currently its showing Overnight - Courier.  I can't seem to find this string anywhere.  It looks like it might be concatenated of two variables since I found they exists independently in the db

core_config_data

path - carriers/tablerate/title
path - carriers/tablerate/name

I've manually changed them but its not reflecting in the email template.  Is there a cache I need to clear after the change?

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple to update your value from admin

just go to

**Admin area -> configuration -> shipping  methods**

click on table rates and you can find both variable on this page **title and name**

just update which you want to add for email templates

**OR**

might be cache issue or try to send email to different email address to test your updates.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked there in the first instance before doing the low level search.  It's not there

Comment: so may be some static text would be there written by some one

Comment: 90% of the recorded rows shows the identical string so its very unlikely every customer manually wrote this string.

Comment: ohh so please check with your store level configuration. there would be different setting for different store.